# How to Default Value in a Form from another Form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have two forms, one CreateOrderForm and one CreateManifestForm.  Submitting CreateOrderForm renders CreateManifestForm.

There is an input in CreateOrderForm 'reference' which is user entered but then should default into the 'reference field of CreateManifestForm.  I seem to be unable to figure out how to pass that value from form to form

FORMS.PY

```
class CreateOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ('reference', 'ultimate_consignee', 'ship_to', 'vessel', 'booking_no', 'POL',....)


class CreateManifestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Manifests
        fields = ('reference', 'cases', 'description', 'count')
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def add_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateOrderForm(request.POST)


        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest')

    else:
        form = CreateOrderForm()
        return render(request, 'add_order.html', {'form': form})

def add_manifest(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest')

    form = CreateManifestForm()
    manifests = Manifests.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'manifests': manifests,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```

As you can see there is a field in each form for 'reference' I would like to user enter it in CreateOrderForm and pass that value to default when creating the manifest.  Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: If the reference is always to be copied the same. Why not just keep the field in one of the models instead of both? In the end thats the whole point of OOP.

Comment: It may well be that this is an option but I’m unsure of how it would work exactly. There are multiple entries in the Manifest model per Order #. For example order #100 may have three entries in the Manifest model, so I was keeping the reference in both to ultimately tie those manifest entries back to the single order. Please, if there is a smarter way, which I feel there is, any help would be appreciated @devdob

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that you can try:
make the `add_manifest` URL have a Parameter like

```
path('add-manifest/<int:reference_id>/', name='add_manifest`)
```

and in your View update:

```
return redirect('add_manifest') # in add_order function
```

to:

```
return redirect('add_manifest', kwargs={'reference_id': form.reference})
```

now in the `add_manifest` View you can access the Reference from:

```
request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('reference_id')
```

Comment: thank you for the reply it seems this is on the verge of working, but I am getting the following error: Reverse for 'add_manifest' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'reference_id': u'219108'}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add_manifest/<int:reference_id>/'] - I am using an older version of django, so am using url instead of path - could that have some effect? @ashrafemadmohammed

Comment: @GXM100 What version are you using?

Comment: 1.10 - I installed this version to follow a tutorial that I wanted to use to learn. I tried to upgrade my version now because I see this is only available in 2+ but I can’t seem to use the Django —upgrade command. It just takes forever and seemingly doesn’t do anything

Comment: put the url in this format: `url(r'^add-manifest/(?P<reference_id>\d+)/$', views.myview(), name="add_manifest")` .. for upgrading: did you try `pip install --upgrade django` ?